# django send password reset confirm email on user creation by admin

Tags: python, django, email

On our django based site only the admin can create new user but he can not set any password and i have used email_new_user function. So on new user creation an email is sent with password reset link.

this is how my function in models.py look like :-

```
    def email_new_user(sender, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        if kwargs["created"]:
        new_user = kwargs["instance"]
        send_mail('Set Your Password', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/reset/', 'from_email',[new_user.email], fail_silently=False)
    post_save.connect(email_new_user, sender=User)
```

but i want to know what do i need to write on the place of SEND_EMAIL() function so that i can directly send the password_reset_confirm_email to the newly created user on the place of sending him this url where he can enter his email address in order to get the password reset confirm email.

Comment: I am using the django-registration-1.0 app.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a custom action for the admin:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Or have you looking into packages that provide registration/email reset options:
I use this one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: i want to know what do i have to use on the place of send_email() function so that i can directly send the password_reset_confirm_email